# animateWithDuration not available

Tags: iphone, uikit, ios-4.2

i started a project with the iOS SDK 4.0 and want to use blocks in order to animate some UIViews. But after I recogized that "animateWithDuration" isn't available i updated my XCode and iOS SDK to 4.2. In my project I set the "base sdk" to 4.2, too.

I thought that might solve the problem. But XCode still complains about the missing method. Is this method not available for simulator builds? Or what do I have to do in oder to activate it?

Thx.
kie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the project build settings for the *Deployment Target* setting.  This is the lowest version of the SDK that you're interested in supporting.  If it's lower than 4.0 then all of the pre-4.0 methods will be stripped out by the compiler (since they won't be available on the devices you're planning to deploy to).  Try setting it to 4.0 or later; that should help.